# Clone button not working outside cloned div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to alter my jquery script and I don't know if i've been looking at it to long but i'm trying to place the clone buttons outside the container but it won't work, it only works when it's inside.

Here's the code:

```
function updateClonedInput(index, element) {
    $(element).appendTo("#upload_image_sets").attr("id", "clonedInput" +  index);
    $(element).find(">:first-child").attr("id", "upload_image_link_" + index);
    $(element).find(">:first-child").attr("name", "hero_options[upload_image_link_" + index + "]");
    $(element).find(">:first-child").next().attr("id", "show_upload_image_link_button_" + index);
}

$(document).on("click", "button.clone", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length + 1;
    var new_Input = $(this).parents(".clonedInput").clone();
    updateClonedInput(cloneIndex, new_Input);    
    $('button.remove').show();
});
$(document).on("click", "button.remove", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
    if ($('.clonedInput').length < 2) {
        $('button.remove').hide();
    }
    $(".clonedInput").each( function (cloneIndex, clonedElement) {
        updateClonedInput(cloneIndex + 1, clonedElement);
    })
});
```

Here's a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d8Tj8/24/

Comment: Can you post your desired HTML?

Comment: Because if not inside then obviously `$(this).parents(".clonedInput")` returns empty object... So comes the question, which specific DIV should then be cloned when clicking on a button irrelevant to any specific DIV??? I guess the last, so: `var new_Input = $(".clonedInput:last").clone();`

Comment: "i'm trying to place the clone buttons outside the container"?? What do you mean, which container.

Comment: Sorry, cannot edit previous comment anymore so: `var new_Input = $(this).closest('.clonedInput').length ? $(this).closest('.clonedInput').clone() : $(".clonedInput:last").clone();` http://jsfiddle.net/d8Tj8/26/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working

```
function updateClonedInput(index, element) {
    $(element).appendTo("#upload_image_sets").attr("id", "clonedInput" +  index);
    $(element).find(">:first-child").attr("id", "upload_image_link_" + index);
    $(element).find(">:first-child").attr("name", "hero_options[upload_image_link_" + index + "]");
    $(element).find(">:first-child").next().attr("id", "show_upload_image_link_button_" + index);
}

$(document).on("click", "button.clone", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length + 1;
    var new_Input = $(this).closest('.clonedInput').length ? $(this).closest('.clonedInput').clone() : $(".clonedInput:last").clone();
    updateClonedInput(cloneIndex, new_Input);    
    $('button.remove').show();
});
$(document).on("click", "button.remove", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
    if ($('.clonedInput').length < 2) {
        $('button.remove').hide();
    }
    $(".clonedInput").each( function (cloneIndex, clonedElement) {
        updateClonedInput(cloneIndex + 1, clonedElement);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change This...

```
var new_Input = $(this).parents(".clonedInput").clone();
```

To This...

```
var new_Input = $(".clonedInput").first().clone();
```